# Bootstrap draggable panel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I made a bootstrap panel through following code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix" id="drag">An explorer panel</div>
  <div class="panel-body">I want to be dragabble</div>
</div>
```

and the styling is

```
#drag {
cursor: move;
}
```

I tried using jquery code to make the panel draggable as shown at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable

```
(".panel").draggable();
```

but it did not work and returned a "Type Error: No such function .draggable()"
So is there any other alternative to create a draggable panels using bootstrap thanks in advance

Comment: In order to use jquery you must add the jquery selector. It is by default $ sign. So try it instead: `$(".panel").draggable();`

Comment: thankyou @ Ftaveras have tried using $(".panel").draggable() even but it's still not working giving the same error, is there any way to do it using javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use sortable or draggable from JquerUI

**https://jqueryui.com/draggable/**

**https://jqueryui.com/sortable/**

easy to use and lot of features. for example on drag and after drop etc

**https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/**

Comment: I know this is gravedigging here - but jQ UI is basically dead. Do y'all know any viable alternatives to jQUI that are not Angular, Vue or React?